# Creating a timeline with stacked entries

Tags: excel

I know similar questions have been posted here but I'm having trouble applying them to my exact problem as I'm not very good in Excel. Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have staff members working on various projects. I want the x-axis to be broken up into one week intervals (t=0 to t=1 is one week, t=1 to t=2 is the next week, and so on). I want the y-axis to have each staff member's name and for each name clustered bars for each of the projects they are working on. But then I only want each bar to show if the data indicates that they have delegated hours to that particular project in that week. A sketch looks something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdNJs.png]

I haven't yet input the data because I want to hear thoughts on how it would best be laid out, but this is the general idea. Any advice?

Comment: what you're looking for could be a Gantt chart or sorts. Tips given here: http://www.smartsheet.com/blog/gantt-chart-excel

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a layout like so:

[image: SO24706344 example]

with no fill for some intervals and tailoring of the colours for others.